# Change "enter" behavior in ido to select directory/file

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to change the behavior of <kbd>RET</kbd> in `ido` to select a directory or file and leave <kbd>SPC</kbd> to do the selection of the next match. I usually select directories to view files in them and I don't want to do <kbd>C-d</kbd> every time I want to select the directory and not the next match using enter.